# Count each instance of a unique value in column

Tags: sql

Suppose you have a table in SQL:

```
Prices
------
13.99
14.00
52.00 
52.00 
52.00 
13.99
```

How would you count the amount of times a DIFFERENT field has been entered in? Therefore an example of such a count would output:

```
13.99 - 2 times. 
14.00 - 1 times. 
52.00 - 3 times.
```

OR perhaps:

```
3 (i.e. 13.99, 14.00, 52.00)
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Here's the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606062/count-instances-in-table1-and-link-to-table2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT Prices, COUNT(*) FROM TheTable GROUP BY Prices
```

Can't say I've tried it on MySql, but I'd expect it to work...

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I wasn't selecting it! Instead I was doing something like: SELECT * FROM TheTable COUNT(Prices). Cheers!

Comment: `SELECT Prices, COUNT(*) as C FROM TheTable GROUP BY Prices ORDER BY C` in case you want to sort by count. :)

Comment: Thank you :). Just out of curiosity as well, let's say we have a 'TheTableTWO' and there's a column in there called 'Genre' which links to these price. How would I display that as well? therefore example output would be "13.99 || 65425 || Horror".

Comment: Why don't you elaborate further on this question or ask a fresh new one and link to that from here? Reason being your original question is already has an accepted answer and it's kinda hard to answer via comment.

Comment: Nice, here's the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606062/count-instances-in-table1-and-link-to-table2